# Display all prime numbers based on range inputted in java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a sample exercise which is to display Prime numbers based on the range inputted. For example if I inputted 10 it should output `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29`.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.print("Enter Range: ");
int range = input.nextInt();

int r = 0;
for(int ctr1 = 2; ctr1 <= range; ctr1++){
    for(int ctr2 =  1; ctr2 <= ctr1; ctr2++){
        if(ctr1%ctr2 == 0){
          r++;      
        }
    }
    if(r == 2){
        System.out.println(ctr1);
    }
}
```

What happens is when I input 10 it just outputs 2. Can anyone please tell me the error in my codes?

Thanks...

Comment: Time to learn debugging!

Comment: Check again when you reset `r` to 0. Does this happen after 2 has been printed? Also you would get only the primes less than range with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Using nested loop in this case could make things more complicated. I would suggest you to divide the solution into two steps:

1. create a function to [determine if a number is prime](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/).

   ```
   private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
       //check if n is a multiple of 2
       if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
       //if not, then just check the odds
       for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
           if (n % i == 0)
               return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. find the first N prime numbers with a loop:

   ```
   System.out.print("Enter Range: ");
   int range = input.nextInt();

   int count = 0;

   for (int number = 2; count < range; number++) {
       if (isPrime(number)) {
           count++;
           System.out.println(number);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your code. Try to give reasonable parameter names. Anyway this the code that you are looking for.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    //get input till which prime number to be printed
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of prime numbers to be printed: ");
    int limit = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    int count=1;

    //printing primer numbers till the limit ( 1 to 100)
    System.out.println("Printing prime number from 1 to " + limit);
    for(int number = 2; count<=limit; number++){
        //print prime numbers only
        if(isPrime(number)){
            System.out.println(number);
            count++; 
        }
    }

}

/*
 * Prime number is not divisible by any number other than 1 and itself
 * @return true if number is prime
 */
public static boolean isPrime(int number){
    for(int i=2; i<number; i++){
        if(number%i == 0){
            return false; //number is divisible so its not prime
        }
    }
    return true; //number is prime now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution)

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int i) {
    if (i <= 1)
      return false;
    else if (i <= 3)
      return true;
    else if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)
      return false;
    int n = 5;
    while (n * n <= i) {
      if (i % n == 0 || i % (n + 2) == 0)
        return false;
      n = n + 6;
    }
    return true;
  }



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int isPrime = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int size = 10;
    while (isPrime < size) {
      counter++;
      if (checkPrime(counter)) {
        isPrime++;
        System.out.println(counter);
      }
    }
  }
```